# How can I link to a specific part of another word 2007 document from within a different word 2007 document?

Tags: windows-7

I want to create a hyperlink in document A that will go to a specific place (such as a bookmark or numbered title) in document B

Comment: http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/word-link-to-a-place-in-another-document/